# Octave - Plotting Rectangles

Tags: octave

I want to produce a plot a bit like a scatter plot but with rectangles. Each rectangle needs to have a specific size and start location determined by co-ordinates. All of that I can get.

What I want to do however is colour each rectangle by another value, z. However I do not know how to do that.

You can see what I am trying with the code below.

```
x=rand(1,10)*10;
y=rand(1,10)*10;
w=rand(1,10)*5;
h=rand(1,10)*20;
axis([0 10 0 20]);

for i=1:10
rectangle('Position',[x(i) y(i) w(i) h(i)])
endfor
```

This produces the graph attached

Edit: I know about the properties 'FaceColor' and 'EdgeColor' however If I have a lot of rectangles..say 100 or so, and I want to colour each one by a corresponding z value I can't seem to get those properties to accept an array of Z values.

[image]

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Two_002ddimensional-Geometric-Shapes.html). The `'FaceColor'` and `'EdgeColor'` properties are clearly documented...

Comment: Yes, I understand about 'FaceColor' and 'EdgeColor'....those properties allow me to color by inputing an RGB triple....however what if I have a hundred rectangles to color....can I use FaceColor with an array of Z values ....it does not seem to work.

Comment: Then map your Z values to RGB triples.

Comment: And how is that done ?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Try putting in some effort before expecting others to.

Comment: The [colormap lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Representing-Images.html#XREFlines) may be useful. An even better approach is to use the [glasbey colormap](http://imagej.net/Glasbey) but that's not in Octave but you could easily make it yourself. Just copy the colors into a matrix and rescale the RGB into the [0 1] range.

Answer (score -1):

```
x=rand(1,10)*10;
y=rand(1,10)*10;
w=rand(1,10)*5;
h=rand(1,10)*20;
z=randi(10,1,10)/10;
axis([0 10 0 20]);

for i=1:10

cm=colormap; 
colorID=max(1, sum(z(i)>[0:1/length(cm(:,1)):1]));
myColor=cm(colorID,:);

rectangle('Position',[x(i) y(i) w(i) h(i)],'EdgeColor',myColor)

endfor
```

Comment: Generating visually distinct colors [is not a trivial problem](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3682/where-can-i-find-a-large-palette-set-of-contrasting-colors-for-coloring-many-d), which is why it's important to actually understand the process behind it. This method isn't going to work if you have more rectangles than colors in the colormap. Since you've indicated you have 100 rectangles, you're in this realm.

Comment: Just saw this post and see that it's 3 years old. Was looking for a similar answer. But why would anyone mark the reasonable question, and suggested answer, down as they have here, with no explanation? Sick individuals who do this will cause stack overflow to be an echo chamber.